# Partial matching of request with RESTITO

Tags: java, rest, testing, rest-assured

Can I match a REST-request content without a exact match of content with test framework RESTITO? Lets say I have a timestamp from now in my request but I don't want to match with this specific value (I probably don't know it anyway)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your URL looks like

`http://example.com/api/endpoint?weight=100&timestamp=1413108487`

then you can to the following:

```java
match(get("/api/endpoint"), parameter("weight", "100"))
```

It will just ignore all the timestamps. If timestamp is part of URI:

`http://example.com/api/endpoint/1413108487/bla`

then you can use [matchesUri()](http://mkotsur.github.io/restito/javadoc/current/com/xebialabs/restito/semantics/Condition.html#matchesUri(java.util.regex.Pattern)) e.g.:

```
match(method(Method.GET), matchesUri(new Regexp("/api/endpoint/[0-9]+/bla")))
```

And of course you always can write a [custom condition](https://github.com/mkotsur/restito/blob/master/guide.md#stub_conditions), where you can do any checks on the request you want and return a boolean e.g.:

```
Predicate<Call> uriEndsWithA = new Predicate<Call>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(final Call input) {
        return input.getUri().endsWith("a");
    }
};
whenHttp(server).match(custom(uriEndsWithA)).then(ok());
```